# How to bind variable from scope and append some value to it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want simply to connect string to binded value in angularjs but fail to do that.
How to do this:

```
ng-src="{{photos[i].url}} + ? + new Date().getTime()"
ng-src="{{photos[i].url + ? + new Date().getTime()}}"
```

I even tried to put function on scope and pass like:

```
ng-src="{{appendTime(photos[i].url)}}
```

But this fail too.

Comment: It depends how you setup your controller. Can you share that code? I assume you have $scope available?

Comment: yes photos and i are both scope variables

Comment: Can you try ng-src="{{photos[0].url}} and see if you can pull a single image? The next thing I would just double check is that there .url param present

Comment: Specifically what is failing? What error message do you get?

Comment: Yes that work fine I just want to attach this time stamp in order to force image to refresh. This is why I am adding timestamp.

Comment: Also, your question mark in that string would need to be quoted like this: `'?'`. But as other commenters have written, you need to show your actual code, not these small snippets that provide limited visibility to what's actually happening.

Comment: @Marc it make me a string from all this litteraly "{{photos[i].url}} + ? + new Date().getTime()" or I get syntax error if try to cancat "{{...}} + new Date()..."

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a new variable in your controller .js file ,for exapmple: `$scope.srcName = $scope.photos[$scope.i].url  + '?'  + new Date().getTime().toString();`
and then bind that to your template ng-src, like `ng-src = srcName`